# Are WeakHashMap cleared during a full GC?

Tags: java, jit, weak-references

I encountered some troubles with WeakHashMap.

Consider this sample code:

```
List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

Map<String, Calendar> map = new WeakHashMap<String, Calendar>();
String anObject = new String("string 1");
String anOtherObject = new String("string 2");

map.put(anObject, Calendar.getInstance());
map.put(anOtherObject, Calendar.getInstance());
// In order to test if the weakHashMap works, i remove the StrongReference in this object
anObject = null;
int i = 0;
while (map.size() == 2) {
   byte[] tab = new byte[10000];
   System.out.println("iteration " + i++ + "map size :" + map.size());
   list.add(tab);
}
System.out.println("Map size " + map.size());
```

This code works. Inside the loops, i'm creating object.When a minor GC occurs, the map size is equal to 1 at the 1360th iteration. All is OK.

Now when i comment this line:

```
//anObject = null;
```

I expect to have an OutOfMemoryError because the mapSize is always equal to 2. However at the 26XXX th iteration, a full GC occurs and the map size is equal to 0. I dont understand why?

I thought that the map shouldn't have cleared because there are also strong references to both objects.

Comment: I think your test is not correct. If you change `while (map.size() == 2) {` to `while (map.size() > 0) {`, the two test will both end until the map is empty, no matter you comment `anObject = null` or not. BTW, I've already tried it.

Comment: Print `anObject` and `anOtherObject` at the end. Compiler sees that you are no longer using them and can remove them earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The just-in-time compiler analyzes the code, sees that `anObject` and `anOtherObject` are not used after the loop, and removes them from the local variable table or sets them to `null`, while the loop is still running. This is called OSR compilation.

Later the GC collects the strings because no strong references to them remain.

If you used `anObject` after the loop you'd still get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

**Update:** You'll find a more detailed discussion about [OSR compilation](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/can-your-interpreter-do-this/) in my blog.

Comment: I think you're exactly right - but is this not a potentially breaking JIT optimisation? If `anObject` has a finalizer and it's GC'd before that reference disappears the finalizer will execute potentially before it's meant to.

Comment: What could it break? When the finalizer is run the strong reference no longer exists.

Comment: It could break in the sense it could run a finalizer sooner than you expect it to; before the hard reference has actually gone out of scope.

Comment: Good point. I guess the lesson is that you can't rely in any way on when (or _if_) finalizers are run. It can be sooner than you expect, not just later.

Answer (score 7):

Bit of digging reveals that this is explicitly covered in the JLS, section 12.6.1:

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, **a compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.**

(Bolding is my addition.)

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.6.1

So in essence, the JIT is allowed to remove strong references whenever it wants if it can work out that they'll never be used again - which is exactly what's happening here.

This is a great question though and makes for a great puzzler that can easily show just because an object appears to have a strong reference in scope, doesn't necessarily mean it hasn't been garbage collected. Following on from this it means you explicitly can't guarantee anything about when a finalizer will run, this may even be in the case where it seems like the object is still in scope!

Eg:

```
List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

Object thing = new Object() {
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("here");
    }
};
WeakReference<Object> ref = new WeakReference<Object>(thing);

while(ref.get()!=null) {
    list.add(new byte[10000]);
}
System.out.println("bam");
```

The above is a simpler example that shows the object gets finalized and GC'd first even though the reference to `thing` still exists (here is printed, then bam.)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a little thing to the excellent answers from *Joni Salonen* and *berry120*. It can be shown that the JIT is actually the responsible for the "variable removing" simply turning it off with `-Djava.compiler=NONE`. Once you turn it off, you get the OOME.

If we want to know what is happening under the hoods, the option `XX:+PrintCompilation` shows the JIT activity. Using it with the code from the question the output we get is the following:

```
1       java.lang.String::hashCode (64 bytes)
2       java.lang.String::charAt (33 bytes)
3       java.lang.String::indexOf (151 bytes)
4       java.util.ArrayList::add (29 bytes)
5       java.util.ArrayList::ensureCapacity (58 bytes)
6  !    java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue::poll (28 bytes)
7       java.util.WeakHashMap::expungeStaleEntries (125 bytes)
8       java.util.WeakHashMap::size (18 bytes)
1%      WeakHM::main @ 63 (126 bytes)
Map size 0
```

The last compilation (with the @ flag) is a OSR (On Stack Replacement) compilation (check https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/1165804#osr for further details). In simple words, it enables the VM to replace a method while it is running and it is used to improve performance of Java methods stuck in loops. I would guess that after this compilation is triggered, the JIT removes the variables that are no longer used.